# Type Level Function in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-level-computation

I currently have a class

```
template <typename T, typename Context>
class Foo {
    T value;
    Context context;
}
```

What is frustrating is that the value of `T` completely determines the value of `Context`, so the second term is rather redundant.  In similar situations, I have added a `Context` type to the class and then written the function as

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
    T value; 
    T::Context context;
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot do the same here, as 90% of the calls to foo are on `int` and `double` and I cannot modify the type.

Is it possible to write a type level function that takes my initial type and returns the related type.  I'm imagining something along the lines of.

```
template <typename T> typename FooContext;
using FooContext<int> = std::string;
using FooContext<NodeValue> = NodeValue::Context;

template <typename T>
class Foo {
    T value; 
    FooContext<T> context;
}
```

As an added challenge, our project is on C++17, so answers that do not require C++20 Concepts will be given priority.

Comment: Perhaps use default types for the `Context` type, like `template<typename T, typename Context = T>`? Then you only need to specify the `Context` type when it's really needed, which according to you should be only around 10% of all cases.

Comment: What you are looking for is template meta programming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not directly with alias, but with regular class, it is possible:

```
template <typename T> struct FooContext
{
    using type = typename T::Context;
};
template <> struct FooContext<int>
{
    using type = std::string;
};

// Other specialization as `double`.

template <typename T>
using FooContext_t = typename FooContext<T>::type;

template <typename T>
class Foo {
    T value; 
    FooContext_t<T> context;
};
```

Comment: `std::conditional` instantiates both side: `std::conditional<true, int, T::Context>` is wrong. We might still have a `type_identity` with `Context` (instead of `type`) and delay instantiation though.